# Is it good, if I insert my problem on public chat to get more attention?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, asking-questions, chat

I've doubt on some questions. I've worked with these with my best, when I'm not satisfied with my solution or if there were any ambiguity.

I've tried to edit, set bounty etc., then I've got some beautiful solution.

My question is :

> Is it OK, if I insert my problem on public chat to get more attention?

Comment: Did you want to write *more attention* or something similar instead of [intention](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/intention)?

Comment: Exactly _more attention_ not intention. I'd seen a dream related to this post in last night; since, I'd written something wrong word here. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can ask a question on chat, but let people know that the question is also on the main site, and try to follow the [chat suggested rules](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3890), especially 2, 3, and 4.